# Get a list of features which contain empty values (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean a dataset and basically get rid of all the features which have a certain amount of empty values, in more than 100 empty values inclusive, with pandas/python. I am using the following command

```
train.isnull().sum()>=100
```

which gets me:

```
Id False
Feature 1 False
Feature 2 False 
Feature 3 True
Feature 4 False
Feature 5 True
```

I would like to return a new dataframe without the features 3 and 4.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case, just run:

```
train[train.columns[train.isnull().sum()<100]]
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,None,2],[3,4,None],[7,8,9]], columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

You'll get:

> ```
>   A    B     C
> 0 1    NaN   2.0
> 1 3    4.0   NaN
> 2 7    8.0   9.0
> ```

then running:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

will result in null count:

> ```
> A    0
> B    1
> C    1
> ```

then just select the wanted columns:

```
df.columns[df.isnull().sum()<100]
```

and filter your data frame:

```
df[ df.columns[df.isnull().sum()<100]]
```

Comment: Great! If it solves your problem consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct :)

Comment: I marked the answer as correct! I also upvoted the answer but so far too newbie (less than 15 reputations) to have it displayed.